# RestAPI Flutter doesn't work anymore after building app

Tags: rest, flutter, build, apk, release

After I've build my app using the commandline:
`flutter build apk --release`

Then I install the app on my phone and suddenly my RESTapi doesn't work anymore. The screen stays white eventhough when I run the app with debugging everything works.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace/logs?

Comment: Could you add a few lines of code or logs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

give permission of `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in your android Manifest file.

then try again to build apk

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind! I found my answer:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27883

It was stated in that issue that I needed to add:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Inside my AndroidManifest.xml